# The wizards burned the earth for a minute at 60 ºC, what happens to the world?

Tags: science-based, magic

Long story short the only "solution" the wizards came up with is to burn the demons off the face of the earth with a planet wide spell that lasts about a full minute and has a temperature of about 60 ºC.

The spell will cover the entire face of the planet, starting from the ground to about 100 meters in the air. While the fire is also magical we will treat it as just normal fire. The wizards might be wrong and might completely destroy the planet, that's not an issue. What is an issue is what happens next?

The wizards will try to create bubbles of safety around the few human cities left. They will be magically protected so no need to bother with the cities.
They will attempt to rebuild outside their cities, if they do manage to actually kill the demons, and get to use whatever seeds they have or animals they have to rebuild human society and so on.
Again this is just for world building and does not factor in the question.

The planet is exactly like earth at around 10 AD.

- What happens to the atmosphere?
- What happens to the soil? Like how long until people start growing things again?
- What will the climates be the like after that?
- What is the biggest problem in trying to rebuild life that arises from the spell?

I understand that those are four parts and if needs be I can split them. But just seems a waste to ask four different questions that arise from a single problem and element.

Comment: @AlexP,
Thanks. I guess it's the animal that will suffer then. 
You can make it an answer if you are interested.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055,
Good point. I clarified the range of the fire. From the ground to a 100 meters up in the air

Comment: What animals cannot sustain one short minute in 60 ºC air? Humans and warm blooded animals won't mind. *Maybe* some very small cold blooded animals will suffer. Really, 60 ºC is not all that hot; yes, it would kill most animals if it continues for enough time, but *one minute*? Billions of people sustain *hours* in 40 ºC air every summer.

Comment: @AlexP Don't forget to allow for the pressure waves that will be significant in cold areas.  PV=nrT.  There will be a pulse as the lower layer of atmosphere suddenly expands, with another pulse a minute later as the temperature suddenly drops and the bottom 100m of atmosphere contracts.  If those pulses are enough to destroy beehives over a wide area (the night side and wherever it is winter) then the bees die, which means most land plants die and so on up the food chain.

Comment: It looks like your world is already built "Exactly like our at around 10 AD" and you're asking how events in this world will play out "A wizard raising the temperature of the atmosphere to 60c for a minute"

Comment: @KerrAvon2055: What pressure pulses? There is nothing constraining the volume. The air will expand upwards when it becomes warm; when it becomes cold, air from above will move in *one hundred meters above ground*. Air at ground level will always stay at 1 atm.

Comment: VTC for a lot of reasons. (a) It's a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609). (b) It's asking multiple questions. (c) Several of those questions are MASSIVE in nature (violates the book rule). (d) That last question is 100% story-based and opinion-based (not at all science-based).

Comment: @JBH
Of course it is closed. 
Thanks for trying to help I guess. I disagree but I appreciate the effort.

Comment: I disagree with the closure. The question lack refinement, but conceptually it should be allowed, because we generally allow questions of type "What if such and such calamity strike a real life Earth?"

Comment: @Alexander Actually, we do not allow "what if such and such calamity strikes a real life Earth?" That's the whole point of the [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609) Meta post. It's off-topic. However, that's the least of the problems. If Seallussus reduced this to a single question (delete three of the bullets) and chose a question that isn't answerable without a library of books (That eliminates bullets #1-#3), and explained how a best answer would be judged, the question could IMO be reopened.

Comment: @Alexander Now that I think about it, you don't seem to understand something. [Closing a question is NOT a punishment. It's purpose is to give OPs the opportunity to refine their question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388/40609) before too many people answer because one of the quasi-rules of SE is that [a Q cannot be edited to invalidate answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302375/395595). Imperfect questions are *supposed* to be closed like greased lightning - not kept open in the hopes that the OP can clarify them before people start answering them.

Comment: @JBH in that case I would disagree with the reason to close.

Comment: @JBH,
Here is a problem I'm not sure where is the solution for it.
If the question is answered by a outside research=VTC, do your research first. 
If the question needs "a library of books" then =VTC because it is too large.
Not to mention the problematic: show the research you have done BUT keep it short.
So. What is the sweet spot?

Comment: I explained most of what you needed to do when I responded to @Alexander. Lack of research wasn't one of my issues. One of the challenges on this site is that the [help/on-topic] states we'll help you build your world (resolve technical problems or help establish/use rules) but we will not help you tell your story. When it comes to the gray area in the middle, 99.9% of the problem is resolved if you can explain how you'll judge a best answer. Frankly, if you can't explain that, then you probably don't understand the problem you're trying to solve as well as you might think.

Comment: @JBH, That's not my question. You did indeed provide your opinion and I said thanks. But my question is completely different. The tell your story point is completely pointless and seems like a canned rehearsed response. Like my points is about dry scientific facts. So. That's like someone asking: How can a time traveler invent electricity in 1200 China and someone saying that's asking for a story set in the world.
I do concede that my last point could be better written to reflect that I needed scientific affects not general stuff. Your choice to interpret it as wrong is also your own choice.

Comment: @Seallussus As you wish, but here's the situation. A question is too story-based when too many circumstances (variables) that are dependent on the story are not resolved before asking the question. Your last bullet, which is the question that is too story-based, depends entirely on circumstances. Where on the planet? What peoples? What resources? Who is available and what's their intelligence? But, worst of all... What goal do you need for your story? Because ***the question can be answered any way you need it to be to meet those goals*** because you've left all those variables up to us.

Comment: @JBH.
I said it could be better worded already.
I did not focus and narrow the scope in the question and in that you are right. 
Anyway thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What happens to the atmosphere?

Remember when God asked Michael to make the dinosaurs meatier, but Mike made them a meteor instead?

Most species died as a result of the ensuing impact winter. [But many died instantly, cooked alive, due to the atmosphere heating up when ejecta from the impact fell back onto the Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretaceous%E2%80%93Paleogene_extinction_event#Effects_of_impact).

I'm saying this in case you decide to dial it to eleven later on. Because as it is now, you are replicating that in a VERY minor scale. Orders of magnitude less destruction. Some animals and plants on the surface will die, specially in dry places, but it won't be a mass ectinction event.

> What happens to the soil? Like how long until people start growing things again?

Some small animals and plants with low water content die but that's it. Plants, bacteria and fungi are surprisingly resistant to high temperature - many bacteria even benefit from it, as long as you don't reach water boiling temperature.

You can resume your agriculture immediately.

> What will the climates be the like after that?

Much the same. One minute is not enough to melt glaciers or destroy forrests.

> What is the biggest problem in trying to rebuild life that arises from the spell?

The demon killing wizards suddenly find themselves jobless for want of demons. And they have too much power. It's like giving nukes to the unemployed. Good luck.